# Float and @media query doesn't seem to work together

Tags: css, css-float, responsive-design

Here's my CSS:

```
div.imgbeequick 
{
background: url('../img/beequick400-135.png') no-repeat center top; 
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: center;
width:45%;
margin:auto;
height:135px;
}


aside
{
padding:5px;
vertical-align: center;
color:black;
float:right;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1076px)
{
    div.imgbeequick
    {
    width:45%;
    }

    aside
    {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: center;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1075px)
{
    div.imgbeequick
    {
    width:100%;
    }

    aside
    {
    float: none;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    }
}
```

The problem is the aside button doesn't float right when I expand the window to more than 1076 px (but it floats if the page size during refresh is more than this size)

Here's a link to the whole page: http://javascript-ninja.fr/beequickcomm/

The aside button contains the input, the div.imgbeequick is the image of the bee

Comment: What browser (and version) are you testing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `float:right;` in the aside class with `display:inline-table`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1076px)
{
    div.imgbeequick
    {
    width:45%;
    }

    aside
    {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-table;
    }
}
```

Oh, and one more thing...there's no such thing as `vertical-align: center;` the value you meant was propably 'middle', but it is not necessary in your case.

> The inline-table value does not have a direct mapping in HTML. It
>   behaves like a  HTML element, but as an inline box, rather than
>   a block-level box. Inside the table box is a block-level context. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display))

Answer (score 1):

May be, this changes helps you to get what you need:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1076px) {
    div.imgbeequick {
        width:45%;
        float: left; /* ADDED */
    }

    aside {
        /*clear: both; REMOVED */
        float: right;
        vertical-align: center;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1075px) {
    div.imgbeequick {
        width:100%;
        float: none; /* ADDED */
    }

    aside {
        float: none;
        width:80%;
        margin:auto;
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```